# bash: source/usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, nvm

First of all thanks in advance
Im a beginner with node.Whenever I open terminal I get this error message.But I dont get any error while using npm.Can you guys please tell me why this is happening and how to fix this.

Comment: When you open a terminal without typing anything ?

Comment: This probably came from a typo in an edit to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file. You probably meant to put a space after `source`.

Comment: @Dimitri yes immediately after opening terminal.

Comment: Nate updated his comment, can you try this ? It seems quite right. :) (search online how to update these files if necessary)